# Solr -- reqh object access from document collector

Tags: java, namespaces, lucene, solr

I'm interested in accessing the Solr RequestHandler from the point of document collection/scoring.  SolrParams to be exact, but the issue will come up again.

How does one get access [Java] to instantiated objects in Solr/Lucene that are not being referenced via factory statics or other means of global namespace reference? Is there a component manager I can query?

Does that make any sense?

Comment: What (concretely) do you want to achieve? Solr is very configurable, are you sure you need to mess with the code?

Comment: I need acccess to SolrParams from a class derived from Solr classes. I am not configuring the system. And that's right Mauricio, why should I need to mess with Solr code to simply access the current thread's request handler?. Maybe I'm missing something in the javadocs?

Comment: If I stuff the SolrParams into the following, maybe I will be safe....     
public class MyThreadLocal {

  private static ThreadLocal tLocal = new ThreadLocal();

  public static void set(SolrParams p) {
    tLocal.set(p);
  }

  public static List get() {
    return (SolrParams) tLocal.get();
  }
. . .

Answer (score 1):

You could write a decorator for StandardRequestHandler and do there whatever you want to do (e.g. custom logging). Then [register your decorator](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Request_Handler_Plug-in_Section) replacing the standard request handler.